# Why is my Handsontable custom cell renderer only working for the first row when hiddenColumns and colWidths is set?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have the following handsontable configured:

```
var container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 data.push({"id": 1, "rgba": "204,255,204,1"});
}

function callback (row, column, prop) {
  const cellProperties = {};
  cellProperties.renderer = renderer;
  return cellProperties;
}

function renderer (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  var rdata = instance.getSourceDataAtRow(row);
  var colour = rdata.rgba;
  td.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(' + colour + ')';
}

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: data
  , cells: callback

  // adding either of these in isolation allows the rendering to continue working. However adding both together causes only the top row to render correctly.
  , hiddenColumns: true
  , colWidths: 150
});
```

With a running example provided in the following link:
https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/sgLm5ev2/

The problem I am encountering is my custom renderer is designed to set the background colours of each handsontable row based on the value in the rgba column. Which works fine initially.

However, when both the hiddenColumns: true and colWidths: 150 (or any number) properties are introduced, it causes an issue whereby only the top row of the handsontable will render correctly.

But adding either of these properties in isolation lets the rendering work correctly.

So does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it?

**Note**

While just calling hot.render() fixes the issue, its not really a solution as this causes additional unnecessary renders of handsontables which becomes a massive performance overhead in larger tables.